# (Tailwind - DaisyUI) Is there anyways to change hover and active colors of dropdown items?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I use TailwindCSS with DaisyUI (via CDN).

When using [DaisyUI Dropdown](https://daisyui.com/components/dropdown/), is there any way for me to change the color of the dropdown item? This includes the background color of the dropdown itself, then hovering on item (CSS :hover), and clicking on it (CSS :active).

[image: When Clicking]
(When Clicking)

So far, I've been able to change the background color of the dropdown itself and when hovering.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div tabindex="0" class="m-1 btn clickables btn-green shadow">
        <p class="text-medium">Testing</p>
    </div>
    <ul tabindex="0" class="p-2 shadow menu dropdown-content bg-white text-black rounded-box w-52 text-sm">
        <li class="rounded hover:bg-gray-300 dropdown-active">
            <a href="page-one.html">Protecting your privacy</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get when the list is clicked color (CSS active) with:

```
.dropdown-active:active {
   background-color: #0B6339 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve it by defining custom theme colors for DaisyUI.

Add this block to `tailwind.config.js` and edit colors regarding to your needs:

```
daisyui: {
    themes: [
      {
        'mytheme': {
          'primary': '#570df8',
          'primary-focus': '#4506cb',
          'primary-content': '#ffffff',
          'secondary': '#f000b8',
          'secondary-focus': '#bd0091',
          'secondary-content': '#ffffff',
          'accent': '#37cdbe',
          'accent-focus': '#2aa79b',
          'accent-content': '#ffffff',
          'neutral': '#3d4451',
          'neutral-focus': '#2a2e37',
          'neutral-content': '#ffffff',
          'base-100': '#ffffff',
          'base-200': '#f9fafb',
          'base-300': '#d1d5db',
          'base-content': '#1f2937',
          'info': '#2094f3',
          'success': '#009485',
          'warning': '#ff9900',
          'error': '#ff5724',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Then use color class names just like Tailwind's color names.

```
<li class="hover:bg-secondary-focus">
  <a>Item 1</a>
</li>
```

Comment: This is the optimal answer, however, since my website isn't running on node.js or a server due to assignment requirements. I'm just using CDN (which has no configuration). Is there any way for me to do it without using tailwind.config.js?

Comment: @P.Z. using tailwing.config.js locally will generate your final css than you can deploy everywhere.